# Fill two dynamic divs inside one

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside one parent div.
I want the right div always stick to right and expand to the left if content inside is longer;
I want the left div to fill the remain part (content inside will be hidden)

I have done the research, but in all the similar questions, one div has a fixed width, whereas in my case, both are dynamic (one based on content, the other one based on the other div).

I can use javascript to dynamically change the width of left div, but is there a pure CSS way to achieve that?

Update 1: We need to support old browser so I can't use flexbox.

Update 2: Another thing I need is that the content in left div should only have one line and hide the overflow. So if I use `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis`, the left div exceeds the length and right div won't show.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is using `display: table-cell` on the child divs. Note that even though the right div doesn't have a fixed width, its content must, so the right div can expand and the left div can take the remaining space.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.left {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
}
.right {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.1);
}

.parent:nth-child(2) .child.right p {
  width: 200px;
}
.parent:nth-child(3) .child.right p {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    b
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child left">
    right div content doesn't have a width
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: problem is that I can't give a width

Comment: @DrXCheng Well, what is the content of the right div then? One way or another, the content has to have a width.

Comment: it surely has a width but I can't define that in css.

Comment: If your content has a width, then this approach will work. I've set the width of the content in css for demonstration, and that p is a block element. Have you even tried this method?

Comment: I put the code in JSFiddle it works, but not my case. Probably because the my "parent" div is also a table-cell.

Comment: It seems I asked the wrong question. Another thing I need is the content in left div should only have one line and hide the overflow. So if I use `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis`, the left div exceeds the length

Comment: This is not gonna work unless you post your html and css. I can't solve a problem if I don't know what the problem is. Simply create a fiddle with your actual code and tell us what the desired result should be.

Answer (score 0):

Making the 1st child div float:right, with width:auto, and the 2nd child div with an margin-right:auto, should do the trick:

```
<div>
<div style="float:right;width:auto;border:1px solid;white-space: nowrap;">Something Something Something Something </div>
<div style="margin-right:auto;border:1px solid;">Something Something Something </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the right div always stick to right and expand to the left if content inside is longer; I want the left div to fill the remain part (content inside will be hidden).

I believe flexbox can solve this.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: red;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}
.left {
  background: pink;
}
.right {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum iusto consectetur aut explicabo, aliquam illo nihil magnam, reiciendis animi quidem provident nulla porro sed cumque!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe so. But unfortunately, we need to support old browser so I can't use flexbox.